# Bloquear boton home

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, android-permissions

Estos últimos días he estado buscando información sobre como deshabilitar el botón de inicio para que el usuario no lo pueda presionar mientras esté tocando la pantalla.
He encontrado que hay algunas aplicaciones que lo hacen dibujando sobre el resto de aplicaciones como por ejemplo **MX Player**

[image: Permisos de la aplicación donde podemos ver que usa el permiso de dibujo sobre otras apps]

He intentado buscar algo más de información sobre como hacerlo pero no he encontrado nada que me sirviera.
Otro método sería hacer que mi aplicación fuera launcher, pero eso no me interesa.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo con el permiso de dibujo?

Muchas grácias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Leí el título de la pregunta en el que dices que quieres bloquear el botón `Home`. Pero al leer el planteamiento... no entendí nada.

Comment: Bueno, la idea era que quiero bloquear el botón home pero no quiero que mi aplicación esté configurada como launcher y buscando he encontrado que hay apps que lo hacen usando el permiso de "draw over other apps". Mi pregunta sería si alguien sabe como hacerlo. Lo siento mucho por la mala redacción del planteamiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugerencia menciono que el boton de home no deberia ser bloqueado debido a que el mismo cumple con ciertos criterios de diseño y usabilidad para lo cual esta creado. Pero en caso de que realmente lo requieres este codigo deberia hacer el trabajo.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
       super.onAttachedToWindow();
```

}

Codigo sacado de las siguientes fuentes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917918/disable-devices-home-button-programmatically-in-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key/7964513#7964513

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas.}

Comment: Muchísimas grácias!!